# IBOutlet property returning "Can't unwrap Optional.None" error

Tags: ios, swift, cs193p

I'm getting stuck on some code with the dreaded "Can't unwrap Optional.None" error in my code.

I'm following the Shutterbug code from the iTunes U Stanford university course.

This is the code given in Objective-C for one of the classes.

http://pastebin.com/LG2k3BBW

and what I've come up with in Swift;

http://pastebin.com/pGtSzu6z

After tracing the errors these lines in particular seem to be giving me the problems

```
self.scrollView.zoomScale = 1.0
```

and

```
self.image = nil
```

Any advice on what's going wrong here?

I had originally put all the setters in the ViewDidLoad function and was receiving the same error.

Comment: Make sure that ScrollView outlet is connected ..

Comment: @Yatheesha definitely connected

Comment: Can you share the sample ?

Comment: Whats the best way to do it?

Comment: Github or Dropbox would be best for sharing the project

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/aaq24nms5ysczh8/AAC_hM7a-6MyMI-ZXadbvQzQa

Comment: I'm new to dropbox so let me know if I didn't do that right

Answer (score 1):

This line is called when you are preparing for segue: 
    ivc.imageURL = flickerFetcher.URLforPhoto(photo, format: FlickrFetcher.FlickrPhotoFormat.Large)

Which calls the setter on imageURL:

```
set {
    self.startDownloadingImage()
}
```

startDownloadingImage() calls the setter on image which is where you get all of your errors:

```
set{
    self.imageView.image = image
    self.scrollView.zoomScale = 1.0
    self.spinner.stopAnimating()
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image!.size.width, image!.size.height)
}
```

Since all of this is happening in prepareForSegue, the view controller hasn't been loaded at this point and all of the outlets are nil hence the can't unwrap Optional.none.

You need to restructure your program's logic so that it isn't trying to do stuff with outlets before they are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Check your outlets are connected. Outlets are defined as implicitly unwrapped Optionals, so you'd expect to see that error if you referred to a property that wasn't set (e.g. If the outlet was not connected)

I've downloaded your project and there was a problem with the outlets - the scrollview and spinner were kind of grayed out in Xcode. Here's how the scrollview and spinner showed up for me:

[image]

**This means that the items are not installed for the currently selected size class.** If you go to the attributes inspector for that view, make sure the **Installed** option is checked for the size classes you care about:

[image]

In your project, the top box (representing any size class) was not checked.

However, there are many more problems within the code, too numerous to go into in full detail in this answer. You have several issues which are causing problems, including (I did give up after a while):

- Infinite loops in your property accessors - for example, the `get` closure for `imageURL`
- Implementing `set` or `willSet` closures when you actually want `didSet` - for example, the `willSet` on the scrollView would be better as a `didSet`, or you should be using `newValue` instead of `scrollView`, because at the point of `willSet`, `scrollView` is still `nil`.
- Setting a value of `nil` to your `image` property, then accessing it in the setter block for that property
- Something odd going on in your downloading logic (at this point, I decided to call it a day, sorry)

Comment: Definitely connected, checked tonnes of times, I have an ActivityIndicatorView too which seems to be giving me the same error.  Thats definitely connected too

Comment: How are you creating the view controller? If the outlets are connected but they are not there when you run, perhaps you're creating an instance without accessing the nib / storyboard?

Comment: The view controller was made through the storyboard and everything was added through that

Comment: Just for fun try restarting Xcode. I've had several issues with the beta where changes don't seem to stick without restarting. These probably don't get noticed since you involuntarily restart so many times with all the crashes ;)

Comment: tried restarting it, Been having the problem since last night so I don't think its a temporary error

Comment: I've been having the same kind of issue. Sorry, I have no fix/resolution.

Comment: I've downloaded your project and there were several issues - please see my updated answer

Comment: Thanks jrturton, a lot of the getter and setter stuff I was playing around with trying to solve the problem, I've done as you said and I'm still receiving the same error.  Going to start it again in a fresh new project and hope I get better luck